# Does anybody know how to attach files on a document item in sharepoint programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

I know there is third party program that can be used, and we can consider document set, but these cannot meet the requirement of the Project, we have a main document and this has several properties and several files should be attached to this main file and get approved from manager.

So wondering anybody who have already developed funtion in the display form of a document in the document library.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to have attachments on a document library. Depending on your requirements, it may be best to either use a list with many attachments, one of which is the main document, or use a second document library to store the supporting docs and have a column storing the links to those documents in the primary library.  You could even do something using a Lookup column in the supporting library based on the first so a supporting document has to be associated to a primary document that already exists.